# "Directory listing failed" when execute "dart pub publish --dry-run"

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, cmake

I'm trying to publish a flutter plugin and I got this error when I perform a dry run. The plugin can be compiled and it works well, source code is [here](https://github.com/xinlake/armoury/tree/dev/window_interface)

How do I fix it? Thank you.

```
PS F:\Armoury\SourceCode\window_interface> dart pub publish --dry-run
Publishing window_interface 0.1.0 to https://pub.dartlang.org:
...
Directory listing failed, path = '.\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\window_interface\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\window_interface\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\window_interface\windows\include\*' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
, errno = 3)
PS F:\Armoury\SourceCode\window_interface>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the project and the problem doesn't appear, additional, the project needs to be cleaned before publish